# How to add debit card and net banking method DIRECT in indian shipping site?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I am a student and I am learning the Magento 1.9.3.6 version. I want to add the debit card and net banking option to my payment method. Thank you.